# How to assign unique id's to every button of my rows and after that use unique id's using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with a lot of columns and I want to assign unique ids to every button of my rows in my table and also I would like to know how to call every button of my rows which are using unique ids.

For example, I have a button in every cell of my rows and I would like to send an `ajax` request on button click. That's all that I intend.

for example:

```
      <table border="1" id="repAll">
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="button" id="verify1" name="txtTitle"></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button id="verify2" type="button"></button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="verify3" type="button"></td>

                </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: instead of id use class for the click function

Comment: @ArunKumaresh,I've used class but it sends id of first row to my controller. I can't use class because this is my last question that I use class it works but it didn't send Id correct.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854890/why-jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-in-second-row?noredirect=1#comment82674643_47854890

Comment: Assigning unique ids to every button seems like massive overkill.  What are you trying to do with these button click detections?

Answer (score 0):

Assign same class name to all your button

```
<table border="1" id="repAll">
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="button" id="verify1" class="verify" name="txtTitle"></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button id="verify2" class="verify" type="button"></button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="verify3" class="verify" type="button"></td>

                </tr>
  </table>
```

and use class name in the click function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".verify").click(function(){

     console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        // your ajax call
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class in all your buttons and do something like this:

```
$(".customClass").map(function(i) {
    this.id='custumId'+i;
})
```

Comment: But how to use it to call ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use classes, you can use ID selectors:

```
$('[id^=verify]').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('id')); // verify1 (for example)
});
```

Comment: I don't assign a static id to every button for example: verify1,verfiy2,... I'll do dynamiclly using jquery.

Comment: Well I have to say, I don't understand the point of your question then.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `click` event for all your buttons in the `table` regardless whether they already exist or will be added to the `table` in the future, like:

```
$("#repAll").on("click", "[type=button]", function() {
    var currentID = this.id; //this is the id of the button
    //send the AJAX request
});
```